# How do I change a shape without affecting the rest of the screen?

Tags: opengl

I have drawn a shape like this in OpenGL:

```
 glColor4f(red,green,blue);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex2f(x1,y1);
            glVertex2f(x2,y2);
            glVertex2f(x3,y3);
            glVertex2f(x4,y4);
        glEnd();
glFlush();
```

and I want change one the vertices like

```
glVertex2f(x_delta,y_delta);
```

But how do I redraw the shape without altering the other components of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

You can't(*). That's not how OpenGL works.

The API is designed around a model where every frame you clear the entire screen and redraw the complete scene, from scratch. Thus, in your `redraw` function you should call `glClear` and then redraw *everything*, including your updated quad.

---

(*) Well, specifically, you *can* in certain limited circumstances get away with not clearing the color or depth buffer and doing some additional rendering to alter only small portions of the screen. However, the practical utility for this is limited and it is not the typical way in which you use the API.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the screen and redraw everything from scratch on every frame.

Comment: How to redraw glutPostRedisplay(); is rendering white empty screen